# Compile opus-tools with opus 1.2.1 (Ubuntu 17.04)

Tags: compiling, codecs, ogg-opus

How do I compile `opus-tools` to use Opus 1.2.1?

I've manually installed the latest version of Opus

```
wget https://archive.mozilla.org/pub/opus/opus-1.2.1.tar.gz
tar -xzf opus-1.2.1.tar.gz
cd opus-1.2.1
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

That completes without error and, I assume, means the 1.2.1 library is now installed.

I then try to compile opus tools:

```
wget https://archive.mozilla.org/pub/opus/opus-tools-0.1.10.tar.gz 
tar -xzf opus-tools-0.1.10.tar.gz
cd opus-tools-0.1.10
./configure
make
```

I now have `opusenc` and the other tools compiled in that directory.  However, when I run `./opusenc --version` I see

opusenc opus-tools 0.1.10 (using **libopus 1.1.2**)

What magic command to I need to use in order to get opusenc compiled with 1.2.1?

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall the package `libopus-dev`; you don't need it since you want to compile using your own libopus.

Comment: I don't have it installed. I tried to `apt-get remove libopus-dev` and got `Package 'libopus-dev' is not installed, so not removed`

Comment: That is very weird; where is this 1.1.2 version coming from, then? What does `ldd ./opusenc` say?

Comment: I gave up and installed the Debian version of libopusdev. Sorry!

Comment: Then please delete your question if it is no longer relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake was that after installing opus you didn't run `sudo ldconfig`

If you had then it would have linked to that version of opus you built & installed.( at runtime..

Note that the next time you installed any package that runs ldconfig the version you installed to /usr/local/ would then be used for better or worse..